# Is it possible to have 6 values in a ring (1,0,1,0,0,0) become equal after a series of steps?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coloring

Is it possible to have 6 values in a ring (1,0,1,0,0,0) become equal after a series of steps, when the only allowed 'step' is to add 1 to two neighboring values?

Are there any particular subjects in discrete mathematics (or other branches) that deal with this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: To clarify: Are you asking if you can turn (1,0,1,0,0,0) into (x,x,x,x,x,x) for some fixed x by repeatedly adding 1 to two consecutive positions (where the leftmost and rightmost positions are also considered consecutive)? Your use of "ring-theory" was a confusing tag in this context

Comment: Thank you both; I've edited the question accordingly. Yes, @HallaSurvivor, that is my question.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no, it's not possible.  Consider $s= x_1+x_3+x_5-(x_2+x_4+x_6)$.  Your permitted operation will never change that sum.  At your starting position $s=2$ so it will always remain $2$ no matter how many times you apply the permitted operation.  At your desired end position $s$ would be $0$, so you can't get there from here.

Comment: Incidentally, this trick is called constructing an invariant; it shows up in math competitions but I'm not aware of anything like a formal branch of mathematics that studies how to do this.